# Difference between a web-service and web-socket

Tags: web-services, websocket

As I mentioned in the title: I would like to know the difference between the web-service and the web-socket? when we used each one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

A [**web service**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) is an HTTP server that responds to client SOAP/REST/JSON requests.

A [**web socket**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websocket) is a client-side API that allows a web browser to create a bidirectional communication link with a server without having to change/reload the current page.  This is typically used for AJAX requests to dynamically update live content on the current page, or create chat sessions between clients, or implement custom protocols that run in the web browser.

Answer (score 5):

Web services are based on HTTP protocol and use HTTP methods to relay data in a request and response paradigm. Thus the client will always be the one responsible for communicating with the server, requesting data and submitting data to the server i.e getting list of customers or products, adding products or customers to server.

In contrast, Web sockets allow bidirectional communication, meaning server can initiate communication as much as client can do the same. Typically you supply a host IP Address and port to the socket. Web sockets can be used to implement a chat application.

The key difference between Web sockets and Web services is that with web sockets you get bi-directional connection in which the server and client can continuously send messages back and forth while Web services are uni-directional connection concerned with supplying clients with resources